# Why are these chained shorthand operators not working?

Tags: javascript, operators, shorthand, chained

While writing a swap function using chained shorthand operators in javascript, I stumbled upon something which puzzled me a lot.

This code is supposed to swap a and b values.

```
var a = 4532;
var b = 969;

a^=b^=a^=b;
```

But it doesn't: b = 4532, but a = 0.

If I break this code in 2 lines, it works as intended.

```
var a = 4532;
var b = 969;

b^=a^=b;
a^=b;
```

What is the technical explanation?

PS: here's [the code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytmhp/1/) if someone wants to quickly try for himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering your question, can you tell the result of the following code?

```
var c = 1;
c += c += 1;
```

You may believe that it's 4, try it yourself :)

I have no idea of how the javascript code is interpreted under the hood. Here is how I try to explain why that happened.

By `a += b`, it is equal to `a = a + b`. So, `c += c += 1` is `c = c + (c = c + 1)`. Assignment in form of `(c + (c = c + 1))`, the result is `(c + c + 1)`. Here I think it is the key point, and it's confusing, the variable `c` is still `1`, although we reassign a new value `c + 1` to it, in the first assignment `c += 1`.

So, `a^=b^=a^=b` is equal to `a = a^b^a^b`, that's `0`. Because the internal change to `a` is ignored, or maybe it's a bug?

My another guess is that, the code may be expanded like this:

```
c = 1 + (c = 1 + 1)// in form of c = c + (c = c + 1)
```

That's all my guesses, cause I don't know how the bytecode generated by VM looks like. Hopes it is useful.